# How to use WhenAnyValue and ToProperty with F#?

Tags: xamarin, f#, reactiveui, c#-to-f#

I'm new to F# and to reactiveui, can someone help me to translate the following C# code to F#

```
this.WhenAnyValue(e => e.Username, p => p.Password,
    (emailAddress, password) => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailAddress)) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) && password.Length > 6)
    .ToProperty(this, v => v.IsValid, out _isValid);
```

Here's what I tried, even I don't know if this is the right way

```
this.WhenAnyValue(toLinq <@ fun (vm:LoginViewModel) -> vm.Username @>, toLinq <@ fun (vm:LoginViewModel) -> vm.Password @>)
    .Where(fun (u, p) -> (not String.IsNullOrEmpty(u)) && (not String.IsNullOrEmpty(p)) && p.Length > 6)
    .Select(fun _ -> true)
    .ToProperty(this, (fun vm -> vm.IsValid), &_isValid) |> ignore
```

And I'm getting this error:

Error: Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized

Comment: Which line is giving the error?  Can you try splitting it into separate statements to narrow it down?

Comment: well, it's not the same code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of this:

```
not String.IsNullOrEmpty(u)
```

Parentheses don't carry a special meaning in F# as they do in C#. In F# they're just parentheses, not a special syntax for calling methods. In other words, the above expression is equivalent to this:

```
not String.IsNullOrEmpty u
```

I think it ought to be obvious what the problem is now: this looks as if you're calling the `not` function with two arguments, whereas what you actually meant to do was this:

```
not (String.IsNullOrEmpty u)
```

Or this:

```
not <| String.IsNullOrEmpty u
```

Or, alternativeIy, you could create a special function for this:

```
let notEmpty = not << String.IsNullOrEmpty

// And then:
notEmpty u
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot